# How to convert hex code to standard character in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, ascii

I have a string "Build \x26 sell" and I need to somehow replace this specific one "&" or any other hex codes into standard character. Is there any simple function for this? Thanks

Comment: If you mean something like `func("Build \x26 sell")`, which returns `"Build & sell"`, there is no such functionality in standard java, and I highly doubt kotlin has one either. Converting hex to char can be as simple as parsing the hex to int and casting int to char. But first you need to parse the input, extract the hexes, convert each to char and combine everything back together. You will probably need to detect and handle those special non-printable characters as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own function :)

```
fun hexToAscii(hexStr: String): String {

    val startOfHex = hexStr.indexOf("\\x")
    val substring = hexStr.substring(startOfHex, startOfHex + 4)
    val regString = substring.substring(2, 4).toInt(16).toChar().toString()
    val res = hexStr.replaceFirst(substring, regString, false)
    if (res.contains("\\x")) {
        return hexToAscii(res)
    }
    return res
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind values like `\x80` (Euro sign in some 8-bit encodings) are not the same in Unicode, so if that's your encoding, you need to convert

Comment: Of course, it's interesting to see *which* characters are represented thus, and *why*. XML/HTML escaping?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [replace](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html) with a lambda:

```
fun String.transformHexSequences() = replace("\\\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}".toRegex()) {
    it.value.substring(2).toInt(16).toChar().toString()
}

val str = "Build \\x26 sell"
println(str.transformHexSequences()) // "Build & sell"
```

Note, however, that `Char` type can represent higher values than 2 hex digits can represent. If your source string has the possibility to contain such higher values, amend the above as necessary.